# F2PY doesn't find a module

Tags: python, import, module, fortran, f2py

I am having difficulty with getting a f2py compiled module work in Python.

I have a piece of software written in Fortran that compiles well on a Linux 64bit machine.
Further on F2Py compiles a Python module that uses Fortran bits as well.

Here is how the Python module is compiled:

```
f2py --fcompiler=gfortran -I"path-to-dir-with-mod-files" -c -m mod_landems mod_landem.f90
```

But once I want to import  that module I get an error (in Ipython):

```
----> 1 import mod_landems
ImportError: ./mod_landems.so: undefined symbol: __nesdis_landem_module_MOD_nesdis_landem
```

To be honest I am confused with this error. Search did not help much so I need to ask you here: how can I possibly make it work? If I put the python module code in the same directory as where the mod files are it produces same error message.

Here is a piece of my (primitive) code:

```
module n_landem
implicit none

! INPUT VARIABLES
real(8) Angle
real(8) Sm_Content
real(8) Veg_Frac
real(8) Soil_Temp
real(8) Land_Temp
real(8) Snow_Depth
real(8) Frequency

! OUTPUT VARIABLES
real(8) Emis_H
real(8) Emis_V

contains

subroutine landem

  USE NESDIS_LANDEM_MODULE
  USE TYPE_KINDS, ONLY : fp

  call NESDIS_LandEM(Angle,Frequency,Sm_Content,Veg_Frac,Soil_Temp,Land_Temp,Snow_Depth,Emis_H,Emis_V)
end subroutine landem
end module n_landem
```

If I recall correctly some time ago this module was importable, but can't seem to make it work on either debian64 installation or debian32bit computer.

Comment: A little update, I had to return to this step and recompile the module. It took me two steps:
- recompile object files with `-fPIC` option
- compile python module with f2py: `f2py -c -m pyModule $ObjectFiles pyModule.f90`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your *f2py* call, you have to pass the libraries you are linking explicitly with '-l', the same you would pass it to your Fortran compiler (i.e. gfortran). Therefore, does

```
f2py -c --fcompiler=gfortran -I"path-to-dir-with-mod-files" --fcompiler=gfortran -I"path-to-dir-with-mod-files" -lNESDIS_LandEM_Module -m mod_landems mod_landem.f90 -m mod_landems mod_landem.f90
```

work for you ?

Best,
Max.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar project and  too am new to Fortran. Using the reference below I found that you import the fortran module just as you would import a library and then call a function similarly.
http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/usersguide/#the-quick-and-smart-way